# Awk double-slash record separator

Tags: bash, awk, genbank

I am trying to separate RECORDS of a file based on the string, "//".

What I've tried is:

```
 awk -v RS="//" '{ print "******************************************\n\n"$0 }' myFile.gb
```

Where the "******" etc, is just a trace to show me that the record is split.

However, the file also contains `/` (by themselves) and my trace,  `******` is being printed there as well meaning that awk is interpreting those also as my record separator.

How can I get awk to only split records on `//` ????

UPDATE: I am running on Unix (the one that comes with OS X)

I found a temporary solution, being:

```
sed s/"\/\/"/"*"/g | awk -v RS="*" ...
```

But there must be a better way, especially with massive files that I am working with.

Comment: try `RS="\/\/"` or `RS="[/][/]"` ? Good luck. (Worst case is `RS='[\/][\/]'`)

Comment: I've tried all of those!!!! But it just seems to be taking for ever to print out a record. Wouldn't that mean that it's not finding the pattern?

Comment: It depends on your implementation of awk.  In some, RS can only be a single character, and when you assign a multi-character string it just uses the first one.

Comment: I'm on Unix (OS X), I'll update the question

Comment: Are you sure you mean records and not fields ? **FS='//'**

Comment: Thanks @Arif_Burhan, I needed that comedic relief after hours of pulling my hair out.

Comment: It's almost certain, as @WilliamPursell says, that your awk does not support multi-character RS. If there's any way you can use `gawk` instead, that would be your best bet.

Comment: What does `awk --version` tell you? Also, when trying to find a character to use as a RS or anything else, don't use an RE metacharacter like `*`! Post some concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, `awk version 20070501` does not support  multi-character RS. Here's an illustration using such an awk, and a comparison (on the same machine) with gawk:

```
$ /usr/bin/awk --version
awk version 20070501

$ /usr/bin/awk -v RS="//" '{print NR ":" $0}' <<< x//y//z
1:x
2:
3:y
4:
5:z

$ gawk -v RS="//" '{print NR ":" $0}' <<< x//y//z
1:x
2:y
3:z
```

If you cannot find a suitable `awk`, then pick a better character than `*`. For example, if tabs are acceptable, and if your shell supports `$'...'`, then you could use this incantation of `sed`:

```
sed $'s,//,\t,g'
```